# How do you tame a villager?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just made a new mall in Minecraft, and inside of it I put in a store and movie theater, and so on. But I need some villagers to stay in the mall. And I need them to stay in their places. I know it's possible because I've seen people have villagers stay in their place. But I just can't find out how! And I can't use commands if that's what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using half slabs like this?

[image: Villager trapped with half slabs]

This is the only way i know of to keep villagers in one location without command blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Minecraft pocket edition and you want to make  villagers stay in your building they must have food like a pumpkin garden and they must have a bed to sleep

Answer (score -1):

Use bars and make a small cage you don't need command block next if your on cheats go to where you talk to friends tipe /summon villager